# Bug retrieving current time on Android with a given timezone

Tags: java, android, date, timezone, unix-timestamp

In my application I retrieve from a webservice an unix timestamp (between 0 and 15minutes in the future) and I display a countdown to that time in the form of XXm-XXs.
So I simply do `System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp` and I convert the result in a human readable date.
Everything works fine but it seems that with certain timezones, my timer is 30 minutes off, <s>because `System.currentTimeMillis()` return a value 1800000 millis lower than expected</s> because Calendar returns wrong value of minutes when I request minutes with it.
The timezone is the GMT+8 of Kuala Lumpur (Malasya). Using another GMT+8 timezone works normally.
Example:

```
 long till = requestTimeFromWebService()
 long now=System.currentTimeMillis();
 long remaining_time = till - now;
 Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
 c.setTimeInMillis(remaining_time);
 int minutes=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
 System.out.println(""+minutes+"m");
 int seconds=c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
 System.out.println(""+seconds+"s");
```

With this code `System.out.println(""+minutes+"m");` prints (e.g) `5m` if GMT+2 Rome Timezone is set and `35m` if GMT+8 Kuala Lumpur Timezone is set.

Is this a known bug?
I found this: http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/363 that seems to confirm an issue.

I also found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Malaysia

> Blockquote At 2330 hrs local time of 31 December 1981, people in Peninsular Malaysia adjusted their clocks and watches ahead by 30 minutes to become 00:00 hours local time of 1 January 1982, to match the time in use in East Malaysia, which is UTC+08:00.
>   This could explain where the bug comes off.

Any advice?

Comment: `30000 millis` that's 30 seconds, not 30 minutes

Comment: what is the date of your device?

Comment: Some timezones aren't a full hour off UTC: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html. Also you could get the user's UTC offset and use that: [TimeZone.getOffset()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset(long))

Comment: @njzk2 sorry you are right, I pasted the wrong number. About your question, I don't know what you mean with the date of my device, do you want to see an epoch returned?

Comment: @DataDino there are no issues with half hour and 45-minute Time Zones (that work fine), but with specific timezones, in particular Kuala Lumpur UTC+8

Comment: I don't see how using a timezone is relevant in this problem. If your users are all over the world, your service should return a UTC timestamp, and you should compare that with a UTC timestamp on the device. Which is apparently what you do. If a given device returns 30 minutes less, the time is wrong on that device.

Comment: what you can do is have the server return a delay instead of a timestamp: instead of saying "the event happens at 00:15", say "the event happens in 15000 millis from now". This way, even if the device clock is at the wrong time, it should still be able to trigger at the right momen

Comment: Edit your Question to post example data, inputs and outputs, what you expected versus what you got.

Comment: @njzk2 I have no control on webservice, so I can't do what you suggest. The server returns a timestamp in the future, so I need to compare that to the local device to set the timer correctly. An alternative would be to retrieve the date from an NTP server, but I'd prefer to avoid this way

Comment: Um, something doesn't make sense here. `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns time based strictly on UTC.  If your input timestamps are also based on UTC, then time zones are irrelevant.

Comment: @MattJohnson you are right, after further investigation I found that timestamp returned was corrected (I did an error debugging the issue) and the problem is caused by the Calendar to get the human readable string. I updated the question and now I have a simply fix for my case, but still there is a problem not clarified with the malasyan timezone and Calendar.

Comment: `c.setTimeInMillis(millis);` what is `millis` in this case? (I suspect it is the `remaining_time` value, in which case all makes sense because it represents a very little time after epoch, something around 1/1/1970 around 00:15, which is a time when the timezone in malasya was not gmt+8. -> don't use a calendar to show a time difference)

Comment: yes it is `remaining_time`, corrected.
Anyway you could get a point, do you mean that Calendar records the past history and remembers that at that date Malasya was not GMT+8 but something like GMT+8:30? I didn't know it, but could make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A date-time != span-of-time

You are abusing the date-time class `java.util.Calendar` (or `java.util.Date`) to inappropriately track a span of time. That class tracks time as a count of milliseconds since the epoch of start of 1970 in UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`) plus an assigned time zone.

So when you instantiate with a count of milliseconds of 5 minutes, you are actually creating a date-time of 5 minutes after start of 1970, `1970-01-01T00:05:00Z` for a `java.util.Date` and adding a time zone for `java.util.Calendar`.

When you applied a time zone for Malaysia **you end up getting the old-style Malaysia time rules for 1970**, not today’s post-1981 Malaysia rules.

So, no bugs, just a misuse of features.

Lesson learned: Do not use a date-time value to represent a span-of-time.

## java.time

Another problem: You are using the notoriously troublesome old legacy date-time classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

If by “unix timestamp” you meant a count of milliseconds from an epoch of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) such as `1_473_738_754_764L`, then use the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

First, we simulate some input data as described in Question as being in the future up to 15 minutes.

```
Instant instantNow = Instant.now ();
long seconds = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds ( 10 );
String input = Long.toString ( instantNow.plusSeconds ( seconds ).toEpochMilli () ); // 10 minutes in the future.
```

To process that String input, we convert to a `long` primitive value, and feed it to a `Instant` factory method.

```
Instant instantLater = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( Long.valueOf ( input ) );
```

### Span-of-time

To capture the elapsed time, use the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between ( instantNow , instantLater );

System.out.println ( "instantNow: " + instantNow + " | instantLater: " + instantLater + " | duration: " + duration );
```

When run. Note the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format for a duration `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates the years-months-days portion from the hours-minutes-seconds portion. So `PT10M` is “ten minutes”. Always use this format for textual representation of elapsed time rather than ambiguous clock-style (HH:MM:SS). The `Duration` and `Period` classes in java.time can parse and generate such strings directly with no need to specify a formatting pattern.

> instantNow: 2016-09-13T19:16:33.913Z | instantLater: 2016-09-13T19:26:33.913Z | duration: PT10M

Note that none of the above code cared about time zones. All the values were in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Much of your business logic, data storage, and data exchange should be in UTC. Only use zoned values where necessary or for presentation to the user.

### Zoned

Your Questions asked about zoned values for Rome and for Malaysia. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zMontreal = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZoneId zRome = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Rome" );
ZoneId zKualaLumpur = ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur" );

ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = instantNow.atZone ( zMontreal );
ZonedDateTime zdtRome = instantNow.atZone ( zRome );
ZonedDateTime zdtKualaLumpur = instantNow.atZone ( zKualaLumpur );

System.out.println ( "instantNow: " + instantNow + " | zdtMontreal: " + zdtMontreal + " | zdtRome: " + zdtRome + " | zdtKualaLumpur: " + zdtKualaLumpur );
```

> instantNow: 2016-09-13T20:23:34.280Z | zdtMontreal: 2016-09-13T16:23:34.280-04:00[America/Montreal] | zdtRome: 2016-09-13T22:23:34.280+02:00[Europe/Rome] | zdtKualaLumpur: 2016-09-14T04:23:34.280+08:00[Asia/Kuala_Lumpur]

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't know why the original code doesn't work, I can resolve my specific problem simply using

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

instead than

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
```

So I can always compare timestamp with the UTC TimeZone that is what I'm interested in.

Btw, Calendar should work in my case even setting the locale timezone (that is what happens when no argument is passed to `getInstance()`), and it does for most of the timezones, but apparently not for everyone.

Comment: don't use a calendar to compare timestamps

Comment: @njzk2 I doesn't, the main answer is updated with code, so you can see there that I don't use Calendar to compare anything, but just to get the human readable text.